# Is there a way to undo a function on a target?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a function done to all links on a page and then have the function undone if a condition is met.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    //some function
  if ( /*some condition*/ ) {
    $(this).//undo above function
  }
});
```

Note: I am not trying to use `unbind()`, I am trying to have the function undo itself. I apologize in advance if this is a bit unclear - please ask me anything you are unsure about. Thanks.

Comment: Undo a function as in execute its inverse?

Comment: It's absolutely going to depend on exactly what you're doing; it would be impossible to write a generic "undo" function that reverses the effects of an arbitrarily complex function.

Comment: Undo as in the links go to back to their original state before the function was executed.

Comment: In the presence of side effects and lack of inverses for every function, this will be impossible in some cases. You'll have to write, I believe, inverses for every function that you want to "undo".

Comment: What is the function doing?  There is no "magicly-undo-this-function" function.  You need to work backwards and make a function that does (or un-does) what you want.  You could store the element's initial state somewhere, then re-set that state.

Comment: You would need to keep track of what was done in your function (i.e. which elements were affected and what exactly was performed) if you intend to reverse anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    //some function
  if ( /*some condition*/ ) {
    $(this).click(function() { return false; });
  }
});
```

**Edit:** There is another way that is fairly common that didn't really occur to me at first. Since you're doing this to all of your `<a>` tags, you can use the `delegate` and `undelegate` functions to register the event. In more modern versions of jquery this is done with the `.on` and `.off` methods:

```
$("body").on("click", "a", function() {
    //some function
    if ( /*some condition*/ ) {
        $(this).off("click");
    }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/
http://api.jquery.com/on/
http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: That doesn't undo anything, just means that subsequent clicks (after `some condition` is met) will no longer follow the link.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Yes, and if you wanted standard link behavior changing `false` to `true` should do that trick. I chose `false` here because that's what I think OP is ultimately looking for.

Comment: Actually, the basic premise is simple isn't it? Run the function if it satisfies the condition. Why run the function for every possible scenario and "undo" the cases where it shouldn't have ran?

Comment: @ReyGonzales That's a very good point. I assumed that the `// some function` part would change whether or not the condition is met, but that's not really an issue. It should be possible to check whether the condition would be met after the changes, and only actually do them if it wouldn't be.

Comment: @ReyGonzales: It seems to me like OP wants these links to be single or limited use functions within the page. There are probably a dozen different ways to handle it, but he's asked for this specific method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. However, it's not as simple as calling a magic `undo` function that will reverse what you just did. You'll need to write the code for yourself, and perform the opposite of the steps you'd just performed.

So, if in place of `// some function`, you actually had:

```
$(this).addClass('blue'); // add the class 'blue' to the link
```

then in order to undo that you'd have to call

```
$(this).removeClass('blue');
```

to reverse the addition of the class `blue` to the link.

Obviously the more complex things you're doing with the element the harder it's going to be to `undo` them. For example, if you're moving the element to a new position then you'd need to store its current position before doing so, that way you know where to move it back to if you need to.

In some cases, if you're just manipulating classes, attributes, event handlers, etc on the element itself, it may be easier to clone the element before making any changes. That way, "undoing" the function is as simple as replacing the current element with the clone you took prior to the changes.

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases like "addClass" you can easily find the opposite function. For more complex interaction it is advisable to write a do-function and an undo-function. To manage this all you can use an undo controller. Have a look at my undo manager, it might give you a direction how to handle this. Or you could plug it into your code.

https://github.com/ArthurClemens/Javascript-Undo-Manager